# Capture 'Modified' [Date/Time] on each record in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, microsoft-access

I have a Custom list in SharePoint. This list contains up to 5000 records at any given time, for employees to go in to rate each record. I want to do an analysis on when records were modified and by who. Not just the last Modified stamp.. but all of the Modified stamps till the record is removed from SharePoint.

Is there a way to capture the 'Modified' state of a record. If so, could you please explain.

Just a heads up, I only have access to OTB SharePoint with access to MS Access{I have an Access db set up that holds all records}, InfoPath Design, and Powershell (I've never used Powershell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sharepoint Designer to do this - kick of the workflow when an item is created & modified.

You'd need the workflow to copy the value of the `Modified By` and `Modified Date` to additional fields, I'll call them `ModifiedByWas` and `ModifiedDateWas` - configure these new field as `Multiple Lines of Text` fields e.g.

[image: ModifiedByWas field definition]

When the item is created, Sharepoint should copy the values over to these new fields.  Then when an item is modified by a user, the workflow should again kick off and copy over the new value to the `ModifiedByWas` and `ModifiedDateWas` fields.  Be sure to configure your new fields with the `Append Changes to Existing Text`.  The fields can be plain text, they don't have to match my rich text setting.

p.s. You might also want to try out CONCATENATE, which is a calculated column - you could use it to create one Multiple Lines of Text field displaying a combined value Modified By & Modified Date.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks Tally

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for the upvote, I'm glad you like it - please could the Accept the answer too (big green tick)?  If you ever need to split out the data for analysis, in Excel for instance, you can use the TEXT TO COLUMN command found on the Data tab.  It's good for splitting out the multiple names of people modifying your list items.